# Yii2 : Rest API return xml instead of json

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-api

I just used Yii2 to build an Application to be backend for Flutter App

so ..  I created a modules/api folder and I've create controllers inside it , like this

```
<?php

 namespace app\modules\api\controllers;

 use yii\web\Controller;
 use yii\rest\ActiveController;


 class AdController extends ActiveController
 {
   public  $modelClass = 'app\models\Ad';
 }
```

and its works fine but its return XML

i tried in web.php

```
'components' => [
    'response' => [
        'format' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
    ],
 ],
```

and

```
'request' => [
        'parsers' => [
            'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
        ]
    ],
```

but it still return XML

**Update**

when i use

```
        'urlManager' => [ 
        ....
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
         ...
         ]
```

it give me **Not Found (#404)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all create a base controller

and override behaviour method with this configuration

```
namespace micro\controllers;
class ActiveController extends yii\rest\ActiveController {

    public function behaviors() {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ]
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```

than extend it in all your project controller

**contentNegotiator** key is responsible for response format

Comment: there is something i need to know when i Used `'enableStrictParsing' => true,` i can't access s to my controller actions it gives me not found 404 what is my mistake ?

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#using-pretty-urls

Answer (score 0):

You can try in the controller action put:

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON
```

For example:

```
public function actionAd()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    // return response
}
```

However you should add the class for `serialize`

```
 class AdController extends ActiveController
 {
     public $modelClass = 'app\models\Ad';
     public $serializer = [
         'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
         'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
     ];
 }
```

Comment: I need the all application return json , Not separately

Comment: No it doesn’t return json too